# Printing records alternative way

Tags: mysql, c

Is there a way to directly display the content of a query in Mysql using C?

What I mean is:
through mysql shell if I type : SELECT * FROM table_name; I get the query result in a neat and formatted way.

If I want to do the same thing using Api C I have to write several lines of codes and the final result is far from being nice (at least this is my personal experience )

For example :

```
void display_Table1(MYSQL *conn)
{
int jj,ii;
    

    char query[512];
    sprintf(query, "SELECT * FROM Table1 ;");          
            
    if (mysql_query (conn, query)) {
                printf("\nErrore query:\n");
        printf("%s", mysql_error(conn),"\n");
    
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);
    if (result) {
         num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);     
         num_fields =mysql_num_fields(result);
         //printf("Number of rows=%u  Number of fields=%d \n", num_rows,num_fields);    
         //printf(" ");
        }
            else
            {
               printf("Result set is empty");
            }   

        // Print column headers
     
            fields = mysql_fetch_fields(result);
     
            for(jj=0; jj < num_fields; jj++)
            {
                printf("\n%s\t\t",fields[jj].name);
            }
            printf("\n\t ");

        
        // print query results
     
            while(row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) // row pointer in the result set
            {
                for(ii=0; ii < num_fields; ii++)
                {
                    printf("%s\t", row[ii] ? row[ii] : "NULL");  // Not NULL then print
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
    if(result)
            {
                mysql_free_result(result);
                result = NULL;
            }

}
}
```

That's a knotty problem to solve. I get headers one after the other in a vertical way.

I also get

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no direct way to print out a formatted display. What you can do, is use

```
MYSQL_FIELD *field = mysql_fetch_field (resultset);
col_len = field->max_length;
if(col_len < strlen(field->name))
    col_len = strlen(field->name);
```

to find out the maximum width of a column, and the space the data accordingly.